# fnFilter, Datatables and negative search

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatables

The things I cannot perform a negative search on one of the columns. The search is triggered on a click. I am trying to display everything but AAA string. It works well when it comes to displaying only the string: 'AAA'.

The code looks like this:

```
$('#checkbox').click( function() { 
var oTable = $('#sort').dataTable();
oTable.fnFilter('[^AAA]$', 20, false, false, false, false);
});
```

I tried to use regexp and smart filter, but no luck.

Comment: Every single expression I am testing on this page http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/regex.html, so expression [^X] applied on the 5th column with regex on, works fine, but not in my case.

Comment: Try: oTable.fnFilter('[^AAA]$', 20, true, false, false, false);  The switches for fnFilter are explained here:http://datatables.net/api

Comment: For some reason it is not working, any inverse search with regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with this initialization code:

```
$(function() {
 oTable= $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Filter Data"
    },
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
  });

  $('#checkbox').click(function() {
    oTable.fnFilter('[^AAA]$', 0, true, false);
  });
});
```

Maybe your searching the wrong column. Remember: Columns start at 0.

[Look at this Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/guLsx1MLWD1SGPLbF5Xo?p=preview)

Comment: I have tested the code you have submitted, and indeed, it works, so now I have a feeling it may be bugged somehow by the server side processing. I am using "sAjaxSource", and I am now sure if the regexp is encoded during the call.

Comment: Well, I should have started with searching for this: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/8045/smart-filtering-does-not-work-on-server-side-processing/p1 that explains everything. I consider mainguy's answer as the first valid one.

Comment: Uh, yes! You should have mentioned that in your question. None of the build in filter, sorting or pagination plugins work with serversided processing. This has to be done on the serverside. Are you using the PHP/MySql exapmle code from dataTables? The maybe I can help you. Meanwhile have a look at my lengthy Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156229/does-datatables-natural-sort-plugin-work-where-data-is-got-with-server-side-pro/22174513#22174513

Comment: Yes. I am using PHP and MySQL. Thank you, I will take a look.